# Normalizing the dogs API

Tags: normalizr

I was looking to get some practice using Normalizer and though I would give a shot with the dogs API at https://dog.ceo/dog-api/documentation/

Listing all breeds looks like this

```
{
    "message": {
        "affenpinscher": [],
        "african": [],
        "airedale": [],
        "akita": [],
        "appenzeller": [],
        "australian": [
            "shepherd"
        ],
        "basenji": [],
        "beagle": [],
        "bluetick": [],
        "borzoi": [],
...
```

What should the normalized data structure look like and how would you use Normalizer to get that?
The docs work for their simple example but I want to know how to deal with in the wild APIs that you have no control over modifying.